# Telegram Bot :Не могу разобраться с __init__

Tags: python, telegram-bot

При использовании request_location выдает ошибку:
`__init()__ got an unexpected keyword argument 'request_location'`

Подскажите как сделать, чтобы работало.

```
key3 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
geo = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Посмотреть на карте', callback_data='geo', request_location=True)
key3.add(geo)
bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='Вот адреса наших точек самовывоза', reply_markup=key3)
```

Comment: `unexpected keyword argument 'request_location'` буквально переводится "неожиданный именованный параметр 'request_location'". Это значит, что нужно убрать этот параметр вообще.

Comment: как тогда запросить геолокацию?

Comment: Без понятия. Читайте документацию по библиотеке.

Answer (score 0):

Надо инициализировать
request_location = True

Comment: уже, любой запрос выдает ошибку